# Dreamweaver CC 2017 - setting default tag case

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver, code-formatting

How do I set the default case for tags? I see I can set it tag per tag via "Tag library" but it's too tedious.

Also when clicking on "Set as default" in the view, it tells me to change it on the "Code format" section... Well, here there is nothing. See images.

[image: Tag library editing]

[image: Code format]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the newer DreamWeaver CC versions have removed the ability to change these settings through the Preferences screen.

This used to be in the Edit > Preferences > Code Format settings dialog:

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=455367&seqNum=2

Here's a direct link to the Preferences > Code Format dialog screen shot:

http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap3_0321384024/elementLinks/03fig09.jpg

I don't know why Adobe removed this from the DreamWeaver Preferences interface.  I find it useful to clean up old code quickly.  IMO, nothing says old code more than upper case html tags.

This feature has been functioning just fine on my main development computer.  However, when I installed Dreamweaver CC on my "traveling" development laptop, I found out that this feature didn't work.

After a while of digging I found out that DreamWeaver CC 2018 (Windows) continues to use settings from the Registry that were in place in previous versions.  The tree in the Registry is copied and then used by newer versions.

It is possible with DreamWeaver CC 2018 to make direct Registry edits and they will be recognized by the newer version but not visible/changable in DreamWeaver.

The Registry* keys to change for Dreamweaver CC 2018 are:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2018\Source Format\Attrs Upper Case = FALSE
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2018\Source Format\Tags Upper Case = FALSE
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2018\Source Format\Force Attr Case = TRUE
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC 2018\Source Format\Force Tag Case = TRUE
```

*NOTE: This answer will not go through the steps of updating Windows Registry keys.  If you are using Dreamweaver CC 2017, you'll have to use that in the key path.

Hopefully Adobe will continue to allow DreamWeaver CC to use the old registry settings like this.  It would be even better if they put these settings back into Preferences.